# Integrate external script to nextJS

Tags: next.js

I want to integrate a script from marker.io to my nextJS app, it should be loaded on every page,  here is the snippet :

```
<script>
  window.markerConfig = {
    destination: 'mykeysecret', 
    source: 'snippet'
  };
</script>

<script>
!function(e,r,a){if(!e.__Marker){e.__Marker={};var t=[],n={__cs:t};["show","hide","isVisible","capture","cancelCapture","unload","reload","isExtensionInstalled","setReporter","setCustomData","on","off"].forEach(function(e){n[e]=function(){var r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);r.unshift(e),t.push(r)}}),e.Marker=n;var s=r.createElement("script");s.async=1,s.src="https://edge.marker.io/latest/shim.js";var i=r.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];i.parentNode.insertBefore(s,i)}}(window,document);
</script>
```

I try to use the [nextjs built-in <Script ... /> feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script), but I didn't manage to make it works.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt using `next/script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Marker.io](https://marker.io/) doesn't provide a dedicated Next.js plugin (**yet**), the recommended way to integrate it is by using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute from the `<Script>` component.

**Example:**

```js
<Script
  strategy="beforeInteractive"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    window.markerConfig = {
      destination: '<REPLACE_ME>', 
      source: 'snippet'
    };

    !function(e,r,a){if(!e.__Marker){e.__Marker={};var t=[],n={__cs:t};["show","hide","isVisible","capture","cancelCapture","unload","reload","isExtensionInstalled","setReporter","setCustomData","on","off"].forEach(function(e){n[e]=function(){var r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);r.unshift(e),t.push(r)}}),e.Marker=n;var s=r.createElement("script");s.async=1,s.src="https://edge.marker.io/latest/shim.js";var i=r.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];i.parentNode.insertBefore(s,i)}}(window,document);
  `,
  }}
/>
```

**Useful links:**

- Next.js docs: [Script component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#beforeinteractive)
- Similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5792) (solved)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way of injecting script with **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**:

```js
    <script
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `!function(e,r,a){if(!e.__Marker){e.__Marker={};var t=[],n={__cs:t};["show","hide","isVisible","capture","cancelCapture","unload","reload","isExtensionInstalled","setReporter","setCustomData","on","off"].forEach(function(e){n[e]=function(){var r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);r.unshift(e),t.push(r)}}),e.Marker=n;var s=r.createElement("script");s.async=1,s.src="https://edge.marker.io/latest/shim.js";var i=r.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];i.parentNode.insertBefore(s,i)}}(window,document);`,
       }}
    />
```